# ¿como puedo usar la librería winsok2.h en codebloks?

Tags: c, codeblocks

Estoy buscando información de como usar `winsock2.h` pero cuando la añado en `codebloks` aparece pero despues me marca error en todas las funciones que añade la librería.

he puesto el include y me pone estos errores

```
||=== Build: Debug in sokets (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
undefined reference to WSAStartup@8'|
undefined reference to WSAGetLastError@0'|
undefined reference to gethostbyname@4'|
undefined reference to WSAGetLastError@0'|
undefined reference to inet_ntoa@4'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 2):

creo que ya se como se hace XD. Si alguien le interesa lo dejo por aqui. hay que descargar la librería WS2_32.lib y luego desde dentro de codeblocs vas a `project -> propietis -> project build options -> Linker` y allí le das a add y pones la ruta en la que está el archivo WS2_32.lib y se arregla el problema.

Comment: si aluhien lo ve me podeis decir si esta bien esque ya no me pone los errores pero no se si funciona.

Comment: Si no te salen errores entonces si funciona